# ToolBarButton not triggering event

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have this event catcher:

```
    WLJQ('button#refreshBte').bind('click', function() {
        console.log("start refresh...");
    });
```

Could somebody explain me why:

is works with:

```
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
        data-dojo-props='fixed:"top"'>
        Header
    </div>
    <button id="refreshBte" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button"
            style="float: right">Refresh</button>
```

and doesn't work with:

```
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
        data-dojo-props='fixed:"top"'>
        Header
        <button id="refreshBte" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ToolBarButton"
            style="float: right">Refresh</button>
    </div>
```

It doesn't either if I replace the ToolBarButton by a button.

Thx

---

Edit:
As it wasn't working for me I created a simple WL project and added the heading and toolbarbutton, here the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Test.css">
<script>
    window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    data-dojo-config="isDebug: false, async: true, parseOnLoad: true, mblHideAddressBar: false"
    src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="content" style="display: none;">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="view0"
        data-dojo-props="selected:true">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
        data-dojo-props="label:'Heading'">
            <button data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ToolBarButton" id="refreshBte">Label</button>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!--application UI goes here-->
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Test.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The "Page designer" shows the heading and the toolbar but when I run it on the Android emulator, I got a black screen!
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you bind the event using JQuery syntax?

The same markup works fine for me using this Dojo code:

```
require([
    "dojo/ready",
    "dijit/registry"
], function(ready, registry){
    ready(function(){
        registry.byId("refreshBte").on("click", function(){
            console.log("start refresh...");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I will try it, but meanwhile do you think my JQuery is correct?

Comment: I tried it but I didn't be able to have the widget showns on Android, thus I created a simple WL project for test (See the html above) but got a black screen on Android. No idea why?
This would help me to investigate further.
Thx